# Waiting for the first unlocked QMutex if there are few QMutex

Tags: synchronization, locking, qthread, unlock, qmutex

I have two QMutex objects and I need to lock them both, `erase()` method. But the sequence is not important.
So, now I am waiting while one QMutex is in unlocked (`QMutexLocker locker(&listMutex)`) state and than I wait for another (`QMutexLocker locker(&writeMutex)`).
But it would be more efficiently to wait for a mutex which is unlocked the first. And than wait for the other one. Than waiting time will be shorter.
How could be implemented such behaviour?
Should I create additional recursive QMutex or QSemaphore and synchronize states of both QMutex with this new object and than wait not for my QMutex but for this new object.
That should work, but maybe there is an easier way without duplicating QMutex objects?

```
class MyQThread:
     public: QThread
{
    ...
    QList<QString> list;
    QString string;
    QMutex listMutex;
    QMutex writeMutex;
}

void MyQThread::erase()
{
     QMutexLocker locker(&listMutex);
     list.clear();
     QMutexLocker locker(&writeMutex);
     string.clear();
}  

void MyQThread::run()
{
     forever
     {
         listMutex.lock();             
         string = list.takeFirst();
         listMutex.unlock();

         writeMutex.lock();
         if(!string.isEmpty())
             ...//do something
         writeMutex.unlock();
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi Funt, just to help clarify, could you post your code snippet for your QMutexs :)

Comment: I have added an example.

Answer (score 0):

ah, ok...

Its a bit of a fiddle, but you can use "tryLock()", somthing like this:

```
// You could add a loop around this until both are done...

if (listMutex.tryLock())
{
    // list locked... do list stuff
    listMutex.unlock();
}
else if (writeMutex.tryLock())
{
    // writelocked... do writestuff
    listMutex.unlock();
}
```

Note: tryLock will return true if it acutally locked the mutex, or false if it did not.

---- EDIT Example 2: ----

```
// Againm, you can stick a loop around this until you are done...

if (listMutex.tryLock())
{
    // list locked... do list only stuff
}

if (writeMutex.tryLock())
{
    // writelocked... do write only stuff
}

if (listMutex.tryLock() && writeMutex.tryLock())
{
    // Both locked... do write and list stuff
}

// Make sure both are unlocked at the end
listMutex.unlock();
listMutex.unlock();
```

Comment: Thanks. But I also need to run some code, when both mutexes are locked. And in this example only one mutex can be locked but not both simultaneously.

Comment: But that is fairly trivial to do using the same idea :)... I added an edit at the bottom to give you a clue :)

Comment: Yes, but than mutexes will be locked only when they both are free. The probability of this in my case is much lower as when one is locked and another one is unlocked. Because they are locked alternatively. That's why the best behaviour is to lock one and wait while the second is unlocked... It's seems it's impossible to do only using QMutex.

Comment: mm? ... I really don't see the issue here. You have a case for when either one is locked but not the other and a case where both are locked, its not impossible at all. You try to lock one if that locks you do some stuff, you try the other if that locks you do some stuff (now you have done something for the case where only one is locked) then you try to lock both if that works then you do some stuff ... easy, at the end you ensure both are unlocked... Maybe your requirement is not clear to me?

Comment: Yes, your code should work. But I mean that in my case, for example, listMutex is locked 49.5% of time, than writeMutex is locked 49.5% of time, and there is only 1% of time, when both mutexes are unlocked. So, `(listMutex.tryLock() && writeMutex.tryLock())` should be done during this 1%. Otherwise it can take much time to lock both mutexes.

Comment: Yes, this is why we are using "trylock", it tries but does not wait. You get the answer immediatley. So in the code example you can try both, if that fails then try just one and then just the other... (or the other way around).

Answer (score 0):

You could do the locking in parallel threads. Please try the following example (I didn't test it):

```cpp
class BackgroundLocker : protected QThread {
    protected:
        QMutex& mutex;
        void run() {
            mutex.lock();
        }
    public:
        BackgroundLocker(QMutex& mutex): mutex(mutex) {
            start();
        }
        ~BackgroundLocker(QMutex& mutex) {
            mutex.unlock();
        }
        void waitLock() {
            QThread::wait();
        }
};

void MyQThread::erase() {
    BackgroundLocker locker1(listMutex);
    BackgroundLocker locker2(writeMutex);
    locker1.waitLock();
    locker2.waitLock();
    list.clear();
    string.clear();
}
```